# Canvas inner stroke

Tags: html, canvas

I studied `strokeStyle` a bit but I cant find how to control the position of the stroke from inner/center/outer. It seems all stroke is outside the rectangle I draw. Is there anyway make the stroke be inner? (or even centered on the rectangle bounds)?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The default stroke do use centered stroke but there is unfortunately no parameter to control the alignment of the stroke so you would either have to calculate an offset value for the rectangle's position and size, or combine two rectangles and use for example the fill-rule `evenodd`:

```js
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

// default centered
ctx.lineWidth = 10;
ctx.strokeRect(10, 10, 100, 100);

ctx.lineWidth = 1;
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx.strokeRect(10, 10, 100, 100);         // show main path

// inner
ctx.rect(150, 10, 100, 100);
ctx.rect(150+10, 10+10, 100-20, 100-20);  // offset position and size
ctx.fill("evenodd");                      // !important
ctx.strokeRect(150, 10, 100, 100);
```

```html
<canvas id=c></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this. I didn't know it was cenetered by default. This is a very useful solution!

Answer (score 28):

**Hope this helps!**

*Instead of doing:*

```
ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();
```

***DO***:

```
ctx.save();
ctx.clip();
ctx.lineWidth *= 2;
ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();
ctx.restore();
```

**Edit**

For me I believe this works because the clip method removes *any* fill and stroke around the already present fill area, meaning the only place the stroke can go is on the inside because else it would be clipped off.

Answer (score 5):

This answer "[Draw outer and inner border around any canvas shape](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34234589/3877726)" shows how to use masking and compositing to precisely control the offset, both inwards and outwards of a stroke without the need to manipulate paths. It can be used for any canvas path no matter how complex.

Comment: Thanks very much that is real interesting I'm going to try it!